# TOWER OF HANOI using C

Tags: c, recursion

I just wrote a program for the Tower of hanoi problem in C using recursion.
But what stresses is how to manage the complexity of such a problem when the total no. of disks are like 4,5 and whats the logic in the two TOH() recursive calls in the method itself. The program is as follows

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void TOH(int n,char x,char y,char z);

void main() {
 int n;
 printf("\nEnter number of plates:");
 scanf("%d",&n);
 TOH(n,'A','B','C');
 getch();
}

void TOH(int n,char x,char y,char z) {
 if(n>0)
 {
  TOH(n-1,x,z,y); // Recursive call 1 
  printf("\n%c -> %c",x,y);
  TOH(n-1,z,y,x); // Recursive call 2
 }
}
```

Comment: I know there's a question here... Nope. I was wrong.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic and is more suitable for [codereview.se]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although your program works fine. May be [this](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~cburch/survey/recurse/hanoiex.html) is what you are looking for:-

```
FUNCTION MoveTower(disk, source, dest, spare):
IF disk == 0, THEN:
    move disk from source to dest
ELSE:
    MoveTower(disk - 1, source, spare, dest)   // Step 1 above
    move disk from source to dest              // Step 2 above
    MoveTower(disk - 1, spare, dest, source)   // Step 3 above
END IF
```

[image]

Comment: @KrishnaKishoreShetty:- That means the smallest disk

Comment: Oh OK. Although it is a little confusing. I've always been of the opinion we must not use 0-indexing when we write pseudo-code. But my opinions are my own.